# Nested linear layout buttons texts cropped off at the end

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

```
Android Studio 0.4.5
```

Hello,

I have created a dialog box from an Activity. Which displays like this:
[image]

The cancel has a missing 'l' and the delete has a missing 'e'.
I have tried to adjust the text size, but that didn't work. I have been playing around with it. But can't seem to find a solution.

Here my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRabbitLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#ff20a3ff"
        android:contentDescription="Logo of Application" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Did you try changing the textsize from 20sp to 18 sp and checked the output?Cause I think the textsize is a bit large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRabbitLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#ff20a3ff"
    android:contentDescription="Logo of Application"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works, but it sizes the buttons to the width of the text, so the buttons are all of different widths. I would really like to have them all the same size. Good effort though.

Comment: Change  android:layout_width="match_parent" for each button....I hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Declare you button with following change,

Just add a weight tag with Button like below,

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"                         // Change here
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I include the weight I get the following: unknown attribute android:weight

Comment: @ant2009 sorry, it should be `layout_weight`, its typo, Let me update it.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your code...hopefully this will work..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I did. However, it didn't help.

Comment: It does display the text correctly in the buttons. But the buttons are all different widths. I would have really like to have them all the same width. Thanks.

Comment: then fix the layout width of buttons..e.g as 100dp

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `android:layout_weight="1"` in BUtton(childs), use `android:weight="1"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRabbitLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="#ff20a3ff"
    android:contentDescription="Logo of Application"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this had the same problem, missing el and e from cancel and delete.